# Upload and fetch PDF from firebase using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, pdf

I want to create a website for a library using **Nodejs** and **firebase**.

The idea is to show resources based on certain topics in pdf to users. 
Can we create folders for different topics and fetch to website accordingly?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) to store the PDF files. To download a file from storage, you need to know its path. You can use [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) or [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) to store the file paths, along with all other info that you will need in order to display a folder-like structure based on topics, tags, or whatever you need in the website.

In [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) you can only serve static content, so you can't host node.js apps directly. However, you can use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework) to serve your dynamic content. You can read the database in Cloud Function using the Admin SDK and serve ready-to-show content, or let the clients use the Web SDK to read the database and generate the views client-side.